# How to set DataContext for all Page or for AppBarButton

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I have XAML page that looks like:

```
<Page
  xmlns:vm="using:domain.viewmodels">

  <Page.Resources>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="MainPageVm"/>
  </Page.Resources>

  <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainPageVm}}">
     <Button Command={Binding QuitCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  </Grid>

  <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True">
      <AppBarButton Label="Quit"  Command={Binding QuitCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </CommandBar>
  </Page.BottomAppBar>

</Page>
```

- If I press the Button – the Command was executed.
- If I press the AppBarButton – the Command was not executed.

I get that the reason is that I have set DataContext for Grid only, but not for BottomAppBar.  But I don't know how to set DataContext for all Page.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work because I have declared MainPageVm below:

```
<Page
  DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainPageVm}}"
  xmlns:vm="using:domain.viewmodels">

  <Page.Resources>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="MainPageVm"/>
  </Page.Resources>
```

I thought I can set DataContext for CommandBar. I don't like this solution, as I need to set DataContext twice for the Page, but even this solution doesn't work:

```
  <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainPageVm}}">
      <AppBarButton Label="Quit"  Command={Binding QuitCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </CommandBar>
  </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Resources`, set the `DataContext` directly:

```
<Page
  xmlns:vm="using:domain.viewmodels">
  <Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="MainPageVm"/>
  </Page.DataContext>
```

Your bindings become then:

```
<Grid>
     <Button Command={Binding QuitCommand}"/>
  </Grid>

  <Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="True">
      <AppBarButton Label="Quit"  Command={Binding QuitCommand}"/>
    </CommandBar>
  </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's often simpler to declare your `DataContext` in code-behind:

```
public YourPageClass()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = new MainPageVM();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This variant is working, but I am still searching XAML solution without code-behind.

Comment: Why ? Using code-behind is often seen as bad practice, but it exists for a reason :-)

Comment: It's difficult to switch between the XAML and code-behind to analyze code. And I don't understand why 'just-XAM'L version doesn't work in this sample case.

Comment: Agreed. The general inability of XAML to reference elements that are not previously declared is very irritating and somewhat not logical with the XML nature of XAML.